# Помогите переписать код JQUERY на Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Есть код Jquery**

```
$('.filters a').on('click', function() {
  $('.filters li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent('li').addClass('active'); 

  var cat = $(this).attr('data-filter'); 

  if (cat == 'all') { // если all
    $('.pokemon-item').show(); 
  } else { 
    $('.pokemon-item').hide();
    $('.pokemon-item[data-filter="' + cat + '"]').show(); 
      }
    });
```

**И часть кода HTML**

```
<ul class="filters">
        <span>FILTER BY TYPE:</span>
          <li class="active"><a data-filter="all">All</a></li>
          <li><a data-filter="endur-pok">Endurance</a></li>
          <li><a data-filter="power-pok">Power</a></li>
          <li><a data-filter="shadow-pok">Shadow</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="pokemon-item" data-filter="endur-pok">
</div>
<div class="pokemon-item" data-filter="shadow-pok">
</div>
<div class="pokemon-item" data-filter="speed-pok">
</div>
```

Comment: Здесь таким не занимаются. Опишите в чем проблема, что не выходит, приложите свои попытки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ключевое слово "помогите"? ))

1. Вызов метода `$('selector')` можно переписать методом [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)
2. Установка обработчика события (в вашем случае `click`) - [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
3. С методами `removeClass()`/`addClass()` поможет свойство [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) уже со своими методами `add()` и `remove()`
4. Для замены методов `show()` / `hide()` вполне подойдёт свойство элемента [style](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)
5. Доступ к data-атрибутам решается использованием свойства [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Похоже, что для "помощи" этого более, чем достаточно.

Comment: Спасибо, я это и имел в виду)